# how to know where my program is reading my int

Tags: c, arduino

I am learning again after some years I stopped and I have a problem
the code is Supposed to to light a LED with changed time of lighting the LED just lighting non-stop without being off for a sec

```cpp
int x = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    x = 0;
    while (x < 1000) {
        digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
        delay(1000 - x);
        x = x + 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the basic programming language, I'm pretty sure it's Java.  Please add the correct tag and remove the basic tag, thanks.

Comment: this is c for arduino

Comment: I updated the tags for you.

Comment: Where are you trying to turn the led off? You always only write `HIGH` to pin 12, I'd expect you have to write `LOW` to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

In the Arduino Studio there is an example sketch called "blink".

If you want to blink the built in led, use that.
If you have an external led connected to a pin, you can just replace the `LED_BUILTIN` macro in that example with your pin number.

Keep in mind that the reason the sketch is using a "macro" is because the pin for the built in led is different for different models of Arduino so the macro is automatically replaced with the correct pin number when you build the sketch for your specific board.

As for your code, the biggest issue is that you never turn off the led.

```
digitalWrite(12, LOW);
delay(1000 - x);
```

You need to "write low" to the pin (basically dropping pin voltage to zero) and then wait for some time before turning the led back on by writing high.

I am not sure why you added the `while` loop, but you probably don't need it.

The `loop` function already runs in a loop all the time, so if what you want is to blink the led in decreasing intervals, your code should look like this:

```
int x = 0;

void loop()
{
    if (x < 1000) {
        digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
        delay(1000 - x);
        digitalWrite(12, LOW);
        delay(1000 - x);
        x = x + 100;
    } else {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Note that at some point this code will be blinking too fast for you to notice.
You may want to change the condition in `if` to something smaller like `x < 800` so that the minimum interval is never shorter than 1/5 of a second.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte x; // 100 ms units of blink speed ( 1000ms, 900ms, 800ms, ...100ms )
void loop() {
    x = 10;
    while (x > 0) {
        digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
        delay(100*x);
        digitalWrite(12, LOW);
        delay(100*x);
       x--;
    }
}
```

Blinking requires to switch the LED ON and OFF and to wait in both cases :)

BTW: each loop() run takes about 11 sec. That's fine if the arduino isn't supposed to do anything else in parallel.

Comment: thanks it was late into the night and my brain wasn't working next morning I figured it out